# Rename multiple files in UNix directory

Tags: bash, rename

I have files in unix directory in below format using sed or some other commands.

```
Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver1.expdp
Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver2.expdp
Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver3.expdp
Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver4.expdp
```

I want to rename these files in below format

```
Owner.Env.File_100613_2300_ver1.expdp
Owner.Env.File_100613_2300_ver2.expdp
Owner.Env.File_100613_2300_ver3.expdp
Owner.Env.File_100613_2300_ver4.expdp
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
for file in Owner.Env.File_10513_1200_ver*.expdp; do
    mv "$file" "${file/010513_1200/100613_2300}"
done
```

Comment: Hi This is giving me error as
ksh[2]: "${file/010513_1200/100613_2300}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: @Shriraj Chris' solution works in bash. So you may run it as a bash script (copy it into a file with `#!/bin/bash` as first line). I would expect people who use ksh as default shell to be aware what causes such problems. Would make sense to mention in advance that you are a ksh user, too.

Comment: @Shiraj - Your question has the tag "bash-scripting"...

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too many (several ten thousand) files then this should do the job (check afterwards with `ls Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver*.expdp` whether files are left and repeat the command if so):

```
rename File_010513_1200_ File_100613_2300_ Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver*.expdp
```

With GNU an alternative for huge numbers of files (and files with strange names) is:

```
find . -regex ".*/Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver[1-9][0-9]*.expdp" -print0 | \
  xargs -0 rename File_010513_1200_ File_100613_2300_
```

Comment: it is giving me error as 
find: 0652-017 -regex is not a valid option.

Comment: @Shriraj So obviously not GNU find (or maybe one from stone age). Try `-name "Owner.Env.File_010513_1200_ver*.expdp"` instead.

Comment: You could also use `find`'s `-exec` (or `-execdir`) option and avoid the invocation of `xargs`. Also, some systems (like Debian/Ubuntu and co.) use perl-rename as their `rename` command, which has a perl substitution syntax (`rename 's/replacethis/withthis/'`) and can use perl regex.

Comment: @evilsoup You are right with `rename` but you don't get the `xargs` performance feature with `find`. Or: Show me the working code... :-)

Comment: `find . -name 'blahblah' -exec rename fromthis tothis '{}' +` will feed multiple arguments to the `rename`, if that's what you mean. Using `;` as a terminator for `-exec` will call rename once for each file, while using `+` means that `'{}'` will expand to a list of files, rather than a single file. See the [GNU find documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) for some more information. I'm not sure whether it's POSIX... but then, neither is your existing solution with `-print0` ;)

Comment: @evilsoup Thanks. And funny: I have been making a mistake with using `find` for a while and misunderstood this mistake... To give something back: `-exec +` is POSIX meanwhile.